# Getting error while inserting radio button values to oracle database from python

Tags: python, oracle, tkinter, cx-oracle

**Linked to my previous question.**

I am working on a project which will basically ask 3 questions to users and answers will be available in form of radio buttons with 2 options. Once clicked on submit after selecting the options i need the values to be inserted into oracle database. Now when i am trying to add some variables which i set already, i am getting error as `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

I have created a table in oracle database called "Survey" which have below fields
1) STAFFID
2) MACHINE
3) CURRENT_TIME
4) DAY
5) MOOD
6) WORK

I am looking help on

1) How do i insert variables as values in to the database? (**staffid, machine, date_str** are the values i am trying to insert in the database fields **STAFFID, MACHINE, CURRENT_TIME** )

2) How do i insert the radio button values **day_selected, mood_selected and work_selected**  into database fields **DAY, MOOD, WORK**

below is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import getpass
import socket
from datetime import datetime

root=Tk()
root.title("Survey")
root.geometry("225x225")
root.config(bg="antique white")
root.resizable(width="false", height="false")


day_selected = IntVar()
mood_selected = IntVar()
work_selected = IntVar()

# creating values for entry

staffid = getpass.getuser()
machine = socket.gethostname()
now = datetime.now()
date_str = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
day_sel = day_selected.get()

def done():
    print(staffid)
    print(machine)
    print(date_str)
    print(day_sel)
    print("Good" if day_selected.get()==1 else "BAD")
    print("Good" if mood_selected.get()==3 else "BAD")
    print("Good" if work_selected.get()==5 else "BAD")
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', service_name='XXXX.XX.XXXX')
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'XXXX', password='XXXX', dsn=dsn_tns)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO SURVEY (STAFF_ID, HOST_NAME, CURRENT_TIME, DAY, MOOD, WORK) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (staffid, machine))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Thank you", "Thank you for completing the survey !!!")

lab1 = Label(root, text="  How Was ?", font=("calibri", 20, "bold"), bg="antique white", fg="brown").pack()
lab2 = Label(root, text="Day", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab2.place(x=8, y=50)
r1=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=day_selected, value=1,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=52)
r2=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=day_selected, value=2,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=52)
lab3 = Label(root, text="Mood", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab3.place(x=8, y=100)
r3=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=mood_selected, value=3,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=102)
r4=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=mood_selected, value=4,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=102)
lab4 = Label(root, text="Work", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab4.place(x=8, y=150)
r5=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=work_selected, value=5,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=152)
r6=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=work_selected, value=6,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=152)

sub_bt=Button(root, text="Submit",font=("calibri",12, "bold"), command=done, bg="brown", fg="white").pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `cur.execute("INSERT INTO SURVEY (STAFF_ID, HOST_NAME, CURRENT_TIME, DAY, MOOD, WORK) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)", (staffid, machine, date_str, day_selected.get(), mood_selected.get(), work_selected.get()))`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks .. this has resolved the issue but i am getting a error now as ` ORA-01843: not a valid month.` I feel this is from the timestamp field..can you help me here too

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual`? Or check your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, default is DD-MON-YY.